# BigQueryML: L1 regularization amount

Tags: google-bigquery, data-science

I am creating a logistic regression model using bigquery and I would like to use L1 regularization (Lasso). When I built model suing the sklearn, I just specified that I want to use the L1 regularization. On BQML, however, I need to specify a float number, according to [this documentation](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery-ml/docs/reference/standard-sql/bigqueryml-syntax-create#other_model_options). And I am totally confused what this amount should be. Can anyone explain it?

Answer (score 0):

Use L1 regularization to encourage many of the uninformative coefficients in your model to be exactly 0.

L1 regularization—penalizing the absolute value of all the weights—turns out to be quite efficient for wide models.

Try out Regularization Rate (lambda) between 0.1 and 0.3, and see if your model improve.